# How to use Cropper.js into Angular2 project with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, cropper

I want use cropper.js (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs) to create an Angular2 cropper with angular-cli.

My directive is:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ng2-cropper]'
})
export class Ng2CropperJsDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input('options') options: any = {};
  private cropper;
  constructor(private _element: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(Cropper);
    this.cropper = new Cropper(this._element.nativeElement, this.options);
  }
}
```

The error from `ng serve` is:  `Cannot find module 'cropperjs'`

But cropperjs is in `node_modules` and my `angular-cli.json` is updated with:

```
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js"
],
```

I do not have any ideas to solve the problem..

Comment: how did you manage this to make it, and can help with that, and give an example of how you do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont think that cropper has typings 
so when you do `import Cropper from 'cropperjs';` it doesnot work

Simple solution would be in typings.d.ts add

```
declare var Cropper: any;
```

It will let typscript to work with cropper as dynamic

Remove import which you have

Right solution would be to import [install typings](http://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/cropperjs)

```
npm install --save @types/cropperjs
```

Comment: Typescript can compile with this declaration but a new error is happened :/

[details of this error](https://puu.sh/tyJfO/aa96779e52.png)

Comment: @Pierre-LucBLOT after you added in angular-cli cropper.js have you restarted ng serve?

Comment: I tried your solution, it is not working for me. Can you please direct me toward any dummy project that you might have for using CropperJS with Angular 4/5?

Comment: @BlackBeard to direct you create a question with details